# In Visual Studio, how can I reference COM objects from previous version of software

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I installed the newest version of Adobe Photoshop. The newer CS6 Photoshop COM object now shows up in Visual Studio:

[image: ComObject]

I would like to reference the older Adobe Photoshop CS5 Object Library, but can't find it in Visual Studio.

Any idea how I can get the old one back?

Thanks

EDIT____________________________________
For now, I've deleted Adobe Photoshop CS6 and the older CS5 Com object has showed up in this list magically. Works for now, but not perfect.

Comment: More of a question regarding photoshop than programming

Comment: @Hairgami - Do you still have the older version installed?

Comment: @OskarKjellin How so? I'm programming in Visual Studio against a COM object. Why do the details of the object matter?

Comment: @RitchMelton Yes it's still on there. I'm guessing it's a Registry thing or something.

Comment: A registry thing means that it belongs to superuser, which I voted to migrate it to

Comment: @Oskar - Understanding the nuances of COM registration in this context is a programming question

Comment: @RitchMelton Thanks Ritch. First Photoshop, now SuperUser? I was just trying to understand the nuances of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you still have the dll/tlb(s).
Choose Browse, locate the dll/tlb (like at C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\TypeLibrary.tlb) and select it.
VS will figure out it is a com dll and deal accordingly.

However if you can't have more than one version of this Adobe application installed at the same time in windows, Photoshop dll hell is a definite possibility. Chances of being able to resolve that without installing the version you want to work with range from slim to none.

Comment: Late binding to a version-independent ProgID is the usual approach, IIRC.

Comment: If Adobe designed their stuff to facilitate this sort of thing that approach might work, if they haven't, could everything right "yourself" and still fail miserably. Worse case is it sort of looks like it works. :(

Comment: @BenVoigt You are speaking above my lowly capabilities. But it sounds really intelligent. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think they designed this so you can script against it, if I understand them. I just don't understand why you can only have the latest version of some software show up in Visual Studio. I'm curious where this COM list is being generated from. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master: See http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2004/06/18/159320.aspx  But with C# 4 and later, use `dynamic` instead of `object`, which will make using the COM object much simpler.

Comment: @Hairgami - Those COM servers are listed in the registry. This doesn't mean that there aren't other COM servers on your disk, but the ones in the registry are the ones the OS knows about. COM is complicated, it gits more complicated when .net interacts with it.